# How to put a jar available at runtime for a standalone app?

Tags: java, maven

I have a standalone project which i wish to turn it into a jar, no webcontainer involved. I created a maven project, and it reads some jars and when I read a Class that has a dependency on other jar (Imported Class) , it will throw an Exception stating that it can't find the imported Class, even though the jar containing this class is defined in my pom.xml. So, i assume that, at runtime, this jar is not being acessible to my executable class. How can i achieve this?

PS: I have the M2_REPO configured at my Classpath Variables at eclipse;

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how it works in `maven`, but when I build using `NetBeans` a `lib` folder is created that holds the jars needed to run the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 quick options here:

1- Add the `Classpath` of your project to the `MANIFEST.MF` of the standalone jar.

2- Create a "fat jar" that will pack your code along with all dependencies inside.

There are Maven plugins to accomplish both options.

Comment: + additional options: put dependencies in system CLASSPATH variable or in java command line as -cp parameter

Comment: Hi, i solved this by putting the classpath inside the calling jar using the maven-jar-plugin. I didn't want to use the fat jar option.

Comment: You also may want to build a distribution zip or something alike, using maven-assembly-plugin you can achieve it.